# The zeros of a multivariable polynomial

Tags: polynomials

The other day I [came across](http://caicedoteaching.wordpress.com/2008/11/11/275-positive-polynomials/) the following statement:

> A polynomial $f(x,y)$ of degree at most $3$ that vanishes at $8$ of the $9$ points $(x,y)$ with $x, y \in \{-1,0,1\}$ must also vanish at the $9$th point.

I am wondering about how this statement generalizes. Specifically, I am looking for a theorem of the form

> Suppose a polynomial $f(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ of degree $d$ vanishes on a some discrete set $S \subset R^n$, which satisfies _______. Then, defining a discrete set $U$ as ______, the polynomial $f$ must also vanish on $U$.

Can anyone fill in the blanks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The statement you mention is a special case of the [Cayley-Bacharach theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Bacharach_theorem). 
For one way of generalizing the theorem, see the beautiful article ["Cayley-Bacharach theorems and conjectures"](http://www.ams.org/bull/1996-33-03/S0273-0979-96-00666-0/S0273-0979-96-00666-0.pdf) by Eisenbud-Green-Harris.